# Change the contents of the element's onclick function

Tags: javascript

I know it is possible to change different parts of an element such as class, value and html content.
What I am looking for is a way to change the values of the function call itself.

```
document.getElementById(id).onclick = "javascript:FUNCTION('"+id+"','0');";
```

The second pass value is what I will be changing. So value "0" can be for example "1" or "2"

Is this possible?

EDIT:

In case this gets going down the wrong road.....
This is what I will be changing with that code.
So then the page ( and script ) is ready to run again with new values

```
<div id="id" class="stuff" onclick="javascript:function('id','0');" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

hope that clarifies things a bit more.

RE-EDIT:

Well seems this might not be possible. So will start looking at ways round.

Comment: Why do you want to change the entire function? What are you ultimately trying to do? Is it going to increment with each click or something?

Comment: Agreed. More information about why you're using this approach would help inform a more robust solution. Generally, @ced-b has the accepted approach. ?

Comment: It is for a clickable item that changes the element it is in. But it has 3 possible options. The function needs to know which option to run. Lets say it is 0 and 1. I change it to 1 as well as changing the element, but then if needed can change it back again. The value comes from DB and will be updated each time it is selected. I do not wish to do a page refresh just for that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but here is a way of doing it which would not even require the changing of the function.

```
var myValue = 0

document.getElementById("test").onclick = function (aEvent) {
   myValue++;
   alert(myValue);
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AqZHZ/